# Generating Picture Mazes

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, graphical-output, path-finding, maze

## Challenge

Write a program/function that accepts an "image" and outputs a [picture maze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picture_maze) formed from that image.

## Input

Your program should accept two arguments:

- I, the image to form the maze from
- S, a boolean specifying whether or not to display the solution to the maze

I is given in the following form:

```
.......
.#####.
.#####.
#######
.#####.
.#####.
.......
```

where `#`'s are cells to be included in the solution path and `.`'s are cells to be excluded.
You may swap out the `.`'s, `#`'s and newlines with any character of your choosing as long as they differ from each other.
Alternatively, you may accept an actual bitmap of the input image.

## Output

Your resulting maze should be in the following form:

```
###############
#             #
# ### ####### #
# #.........# #
# #.#######.# #
# #.#.......# #
###.#.#########
....#.#........
#####.#.#######
#  ...#.....  #
# #.#######.# #
# #.........# #
# ####### ### #
#   #       # #
###############
```

where `#`'s denote walls, `.`'s denote portions of the path that are part of the solution, and spaces are paths excluded from the solution. The `.`'s may be replaced by spaces if S is false. Again, characters may be swaped with other characters of your choosing or you may output an actual bitmap of the maze with the solution highlighted.

## Additional Details

- Paths must be one cell wide (cannot have giant pool of empty space be the path)
- The maze must not contain any loops
- The maze must be fully connected (all cells must be reachable from the entrance/exit)
- The maze must be surrounded by walls (unless its an entrance/exit)
- The solution path must not include dead-ends
- There must be exactly 1 entrance and 1 exit for the maze
- The entrance and exit must be aligned to the edge of the grid and adjacent to a cell included in the solution path
- You may choose where the entrance and exit are placed
- You may assume that a valid path can be formed from the given input image

(Added for clarification) The diagram below shows how the solution path is correlated to the input image:

```
Input (I): |    Output:            |    Corresponding Cells: 
           |                       |    (@'s denote #'s from I)
           |                       |
.......    |    ###############    |    ###############
.#####.    |    #             #    |    #             #
.#####.    |    # ### ####### #    |    # ### ####### #
#######    |    # #.........# #    |    # #@.@.@.@.@# #
.#####.    |    # #.#######.# #    |    # #.#######.# #
.#####.    |    # #.#.......# #    |    # #@#@.@.@.@# #
.......    |    ###.#.#########    |    ###.#.#########
           |    ....#.#........    |    .@.@#@#@.@.@.@.
           |    #####.#.#######    |    #####.#.#######
           |    #  ...#.....  #    |    #  @.@#@.@.@  #
           |    # #.#######.# #    |    # #.#######.# #
           |    # #.........# #    |    # #@.@.@.@.@# #
           |    # ####### ### #    |    # ####### ### #
           |    #   #       # #    |    #   #       # #
           |    ###############    |    ###############
           |                       |
```

## Test Cases

Watering can example from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picture_maze):

Input:

```
..................
..................
.......####.......
......##..##......
.....##....##....#
.....#......#...##
.#############.##.
##..############..
#...###########...
#...##########....
#...##########....
#...##########....
#...##########....
....##########....
....##########....
....##########....
..................
..................
```

Output (S=false):

```
#####################################
#   #     #   #   #     #           #
# ### ### ### # # ##### ### ### ### #
#     # #   # # #         # #   # # #
# ### # ##### # ########### # ### # #
# # #         #           # # #   # #
# # # ### ##### # ### ### # ### ### #
#   # # #   #   # # #   # #   # #   #
# ### # ##### ##### ### ##### # # ###
# #   #       #   #   #       # # #  
### ####### ### ### # ### ##### ### #
#   #     # #   #   #   # #   # #   #
# ### ##### # ### ####### # # # # # #
# #       #             #   # #   # #
# # ##### ############# ### ### ### #
#   #   #       #     #   # #   # # #
# ### # ####### # ### ### # # ### # #
# # # #         #   # #   #   #     #
# # # ### ######### # # ##### # #####
# #   # # #       # #   #   # # #   #
# ##### # # ##### # ##### # # ### # #
#       # #   #   # #     # #   # # #
# ### ### ### # ### # ##### ####### #
#   # # #     # #   # #       #     #
# # # # ####### # ### # ##### # ### #
  # # # #   #   #     #     # #   # #
### # # # # # ############# # ### # #
#   # # # #   #         #   # #   # #
##### # # ##### ####### # ### ##### #
#     # # #   #       # #   #       #
##### # # # # ####### # ### #########
#     #     #         #       #     #
# ### ######### ############# # #####
# # #   #     # #       #     #     #
# # ######### # ####### ####### ### #
#             #                 #   #
#####################################
```

Output (S=true):

```
#####################################
#   #     #   #   #     #           #
# ### ### ### # # ##### ### ### ### #
#     # #   # # #         # #   # # #
# ### # ##### # ########### # ### # #
# # #         #.......    # # #   # #
# # # ### #####.# ###.### # ### ### #
#   # # #   #...# # #...# #   # #   #
# ### # #####.##### ###.##### # # ###
# #   #    ...#   #   #...    # # #..
### #######.### ### # ###.##### ###.#
#   #     #.#   #   #   #.#   # #...#
# ### #####.# ### #######.# # # #.# #
# #.......#.............#...# #...# #
# #.#####.#############.###.###.### #
#...#   #.......#.....#...#.#...# # #
#.### # #######.#.###.###.#.#.### # #
#.# # #  .......#...#.#...#...#     #
#.# # ###.#########.#.#.##### # #####
#.#   # #.#.......#.#...#...# # #   #
#.##### #.#.#####.#.#####.#.# ### # #
#.      #.#...#...#.#.....#.#   # # #
#.### ###.###.#.###.#.#####.####### #
#.  # # #.....#.#...#.#.....  #     #
#.# # # #######.#.###.#.##### # ### #
..# # # #...#...#.....#.....# #   # #
### # # #.#.#.#############.# ### # #
#   # # #.#...#.........#...# #   # #
##### # #.#####.#######.#.### ##### #
#     # #.#...#.......#.#...#       #
##### # #.#.#.#######.#.###.#########
#     #  ...#.........#.....  #     #
# ### ######### ############# # #####
# # #   #     # #       #     #     #
# # ######### # ####### ####### ### #
#             #                 #   #
#####################################
```

Bitmap example (same maze as above):

Input: [image: Input bitmap] Output (S=false): [image: Output bitmap solution unhighlighted] Output (S=true): [image: Output bitmap solution highlighted]

Comment: It might just be me, but I don't see the input picture in the output maze.

Comment: @mike-bufardeci Added a diagram showing the input picture in the output maze. Hope that helps!

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a rule requiring that the maze is connected. [Would this be a valid solution?](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=sBah3ArE) There also doesn't seem to be a rule that the grid must be surrounded by walls (unless every non-wall is considered an entrance or exit). [Would this be a valid solution?](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=evZkKpg7)

Comment: Also, please add some more test cases.

Comment: @MartinBüttner The maze should be fully connected and surrounded by walls, edited the question clarifying these points.

Comment: @flawr Added more test cases.

Answer (score 12):

## Python 3, 1491 Bytes

I found this to be a fun project and very interesting (and somewhat lengthy). When I saw this, I was reminded of the summer I spent exclusively writing and improving a maze generation algorithm and instantly got to work on this.

After a while, I had an initial draft around 6000 bytes long and I spent the next couple of hours condensing it into the following program:

```
import random;R=range;L=len;T=sorted;P=print;N=random.randint;d='#';A=abs
def M(I,S):
 I=I.rsplit('\n');G=[[0]*(1+L(I[0])*2)for i in R(1+L(I)*2)]
 for i in R(L(I)):*G[1::2][i][1::2],=I[i]
 l=L(G[0])-2;c=E(G,l,-2);G[c][-1]=1;e=[c,l];c=E(G,1,2);G[c][:2]=1,1;s=[c,1]
 while s!=e:
  o=[];Q(G,s,e,-2,0,o,0);Q(G,s,e,0,2,o,1);Q(G,s,e,2,0,o,2);Q(G,s,e,0,-2,o,3);o=T(o,key=lambda x:(x[2],-x[1]))[0][0]
  if o==0:G[s[0]-1][s[1]]=1;s[0]-=2
  elif o==1:G[s[0]][s[1]+1]=1;s[1]+=2
  elif o==2:G[s[0]+1][s[1]]=1;s[0]+=2
  else:G[s[0]][s[1]-1]=1;s[1]-=2
  G[s[0]][s[1]]=1
 while 1 in['.'in x for x in G]:
  r=N(1,L(I))*2-1;c=N(1,L(I[0]))*2-1
  if G[r][c]in[1,2]:
   o=[];F(G,r-2,c,o,0);F(G,r,c+2,o,1);F(G,r+2,c,o,2);F(G,r,c-2,o,3)
   try:
    if o[0]==0:G[r-1][c]=2;G[r-2][c]=2
    elif o[0]==1:G[r][c+1]=2;G[r][c+2]=2
    elif o[0]==2:G[r+1][c]=2;G[r+2][c]=2
    else:G[r][c-1]=2;G[r][c-2]=2
   except:0
 *s,='#  '
 if S:s[1]='.'
 for x in G:P(*[s[y]for y in x],sep='')
def Q(G,s,e,x,y,o,a,n=0):
 c=lambda x,y:G[s[0]+x][s[1]+y]is d
 try:
  if c(x,y):
   try:n+=c(2*x,2*y)
   except:0
   try:n+=c(x+A(x)-2,y+A(y)-2)
   except:0
   try:n+=c(x-A(x)+2,y-A(y)+2)
   except:0
   o+=[[a,((s[0]+x-e[0])**2+(s[1]+y-e[1])**2)**.5,n]]
 except:0
def F(G,r,c,o,a):
 try:
  if G[r][c]is'.':o+=[a]
 except:0
def E(G,y,z):
 c=[]
 for x in R(1,L(G)-1,2):
  n=0
  try:n+=G[x-2][y]==d
  except:0
  try:n+=G[x+2][y]==d
  except:0
  n+=G[x][y+z]==d
  if G[x][y]==d:c+=[[x,n]]
 if L(c)>1:c=T(c,key=lambda x:x[1])
 return c[0][0]
```

Which is about as non-sensical to look at as an ascii-art maze is...

It's worth noting that, since the random function is not used until after the correct path has been found, no matter how many times the same input is given, the route from the start to the end will be the same and, while this program does work for the above examples, sometimes it will be unable to find a solution if it 'drives itself into a wall' so to speak.

When running the above examples, it gives this:

```
>>> M('''.......
.#####.
.#####.
#######
.#####.
.#####.
.......''',True)
###############
# # #   # #   #
# # # ### # # #
# #...#.....# #
# #.#.#.###.###
#  .#.#.#...# #
###.#.#.#.### #
....#.#.#.#....
# ###.#.#.#.###
# #...#.#.#.  #
# #.###.#.#.# #
# #.....#...# #
### ####### # #
#         # # #
###############
>>>
```

this:

```
>>> M('''..................
..................
.......####.......
......##..##......
.....##....##....#
.....#......#...##
.#############.##.
##..############..
#...###########...
#...##########....
#...##########....
#...##########....
#...##########....
....##########....
....##########....
....##########....
..................
..................''',False)
#####################################
# #     #   # # #   # #   # # # # # #
# ### ##### # # # ### # ### # # # # #
#   # # #   #   # # # #   # # #   # #
### # # ### # ### # # # ### # ### # #
# #     #   # #         # # # # # # #
# ### ##### # # ##### ### # # # # # #
# # #   #   #     # #   # # # # # # #
# # # ##### # ##### ### # # # # # # #
# # # #         # # #         #      
# # # # # # ##### # ### # ######### #
# #   # # # #   # # # # # # # # #   #
# # ####### # ### # # ### # # # # # #
#         # #           #   #     # #
### ##### # # ######### ### ### ### #
#     #   # # #   #   #     #   # # #
# ### ### # # # # # # ####### ### # #
#   # #   # # # # # # #   #       # #
# ##### # # # # # # # # # # # ##### #
#   #   # # # # # # # # #   #     # #
# ####### # # # # # # # #############
#   #     # # # # # # #         #   #
# ####### # # # # # # ##### ##### # #
#   #     # # # # # #           # # #
# ### ### # # # # # ######### ### ###
    # #   # # # # #         #   #   #
# ### # # # # # # ######### ##### ###
#   # # # # # # #                 # #
# # # ### # # # ################### #
# # # # # # # #               #     #
# ### # # # # ############# ### ### #
# # # #     #                     # #
# # ##### # # # ##### # # ##### ### #
# # #     # # #     # # #     #   # #
### ##### # ### # # # ##### # ### # #
#         #   # # # #     # #   # # #
#####################################
>>>
```

and this:

```
>>> M('''..................
..................
.......####.......
......##..##......
.....##....##....#
.....#......#...##
.#############.##.
##..############..
#...###########...
#...##########....
#...##########....
#...##########....
#...##########....
....##########....
....##########....
....##########....
..................
..................''',True)
#####################################
#     #     # #   # # # # # # #     #
##### # # ### ### # # # # # # ### # #
# # # # # # # #     # # # # # # # # #
# # # ### # # ##### # # # # # # # ###
#   # #   # # #.......# #     #   # #
### # ### # # #.#####.# # ####### # #
#   # #   # #...#   #...#   # #   # #
### # ### # #.# # ### #.# ### ### # #
# # # # # #...# #   # #...  # #   #..
# # # # # #.# ### #######.### ### #.#
# #     #  .# #   # # #  .    # #...#
# # #######.##### # # ###.##### #.# #
#  .......#.#...........#...# #...# #
###.# ###.#.#.#########.###.# #.### #
#...# #  .#.#.#...#...#.....#...  # #
#.#######.#.#.#.#.#.#.#######.#######
#.    #  .#.#.#.#.#.#.#...#...#     #
#.#######.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.### #####
#.    #  .#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#...        #
#.#######.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#############
#.    # #.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.....        #
#.##### #.#.#.#.#.#.#.#####.#########
#.  #    .#.#.#.#.#.#.......  # #   #
#.# # ###.#.#.#.#.#.########### # ###
..# # #  .#.#.#.#.#.........#   # # #
# # #####.#.#.#.#.#########.# ### # #
# # #    .#.#.#.#...........        #
#########.#.#.#.############### #####
#   #    .#.#.#.............# #     #
### # ###.#.#.#############.# ##### #
#     #  ...#...............      # #
##### # # ### # # # # ### # # ##### #
#     # #   # # # # #   # # #   #   #
####### # ### # # # ##### # ####### #
#       # #   # # #     # #       # #
#####################################
>>>
```

For anyone who'd like to try running this program themselves, use the command `M(Image, Show solution)`. I would recommend using the triple-quotes to input the image since otherwise there'll be a lot of back slashes or newline characters involved.

Comment: Accurate nickname :p

Comment: Nice work! Some tips: Use `0` instead of `pass`, `l.append(a);l.append(b)` -> `l+=a,b`, `l.append(a)` -> `l+=[a]`, it might be worth assigning `'#'` to a variable, and `def E(G,y,z):\n c=[]` -> `def E(G,y,z,c=[]):`

Comment: Also, `if G[r][c]==1 or G[r][c]==2:` -> `if 0<G[r][c]<3:`, `s=[0]\n for x in R(L(I[0])*2):s+=[0]` -> `s=[0]*(1+L(I[0])*2)` and (I think, haven't tested it though) `G=[s]` -> `*G=s`.

Comment: @Loovjo Thanks for the advice, the `except:0`, `l+=a,b` and `s=[0]*(1+L(I[0])*2)` really helped. Unfortunately, for whatever reason, assigning c in the function call doesn't reset it over multiple calls which meant it stopped working, G[r][c] can be a string so I can't use < or > on it and the *G=s gave me a syntax error. Still, great advice.

Comment: @AnonymousNoLifer No problems. Also, if `G[r][c]` can be a string, `G[r][c]in[1,2]` should work.